# Visual Studio 2015 is crashing when searching from Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 is crashing when searching from Solution Explorer. Is this known bug ? is there any workaround.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015, Version 14.0.23107.0

> From Event Viewer:

.NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5485 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7098CE82) (0)

Comment: You should report visual studio bugs here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback

Comment: I'm using the exact same version and my search works fine. Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Without any information, it's impossible to help. Crashing with what message? Did you check at least Event Viewer to see if there are any error events? You may have a broken installation that will be fixed with a repair, or a bad extension that you will have to remove

Comment: Event Viewer log says: .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5485 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7098CE82) (0)

Comment: I'm reproducing with a simple test project created in 2013 using .net 4.5. Bare bones install.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 RC seems to have fixed this issue. Update: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx Github: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/7941

Answer (score 2):

There's an active bug for this issue.

You can read up on it [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1606999/vs-2015-professional-crash-when-searching-from-solution-explorer)

From the comments, you can see that Safe Mode might have some success, but no official workaround is to be found in the bug report as of yet.

Comment: That "active bug" contains almost no information, nor was it confirmed. If Safe Mode works, it probably means that an extension is causing problems in this specific case only.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's why I said it's an active bug, not an accepted bug. The OP of the bug report also states he hasn't installed any extensions.

Comment: And that's why the answer is "contact support". There is no information (not even a crash report) that hints that this is an actual bug instead of a problem with the dev machine. I predict that bug will be closed just like this question

Answer (score 2):

I'm the one who filed the BUG in connect. It has three attached files, two crash dumps and one stack trace obtained from the event viewer. If you look at the connect BUG, you will see that another person can repro the bug and this case will be the third (please click on repro "I can too").

I have an active thread on MSDN community forums where you can watch the complete stack trace of two crashs, in text format [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/016c71fa-6a7c-4d76-a07a-5910ce6f57dc/visual-studio-professional-2015-constant-crash?forum=visualstudiogeneral).

I'm a member of a developer team looking to move forward to VS 2015 and we need to migrate these existing projects, so I'm stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

What I have tried so far: reset user settings, delete the SUO files, with no success. Safe mode works, so it's probably an extension (not sure if it's an extension in VS 2012 or 2015, as in 2015 there are no extensions that I can disable), I'm trying now the last suggestion from the MSDN thread and I will post here if I can solve this.

MC

Answer (score 2):

One of our team of developers found the BUG and how to reproduce it in a new project in VS 2015:

1. Create a new VB windows forms project
2. Add a class like this:

   ```
   Public class1

       Public event Test(byval a as string)

   End Class
   ```
3. Save files and project
4. Go to Solution Explorer and search Test
5. VS Crashs

If you declare the event as EventHandler it doesn't crash. The VS 2012 Solutions we are migrating use several events declared like this, the files I found to cause the crash contained events declared like this.

So it's a BUG, you can repro it. Also, one of the projects contains 20k files and VS keeps freezing every 5 minutes, we are investigating that issue too.

I commented the connect issue [Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1606999/vs-2015-professional-crash-when-searching-from-solution-explorer) and I'm posting a new one.

WORKAROUND: declare delegates like:

```
Public Delegate Sub MyEventHandler(ByVal s As String)
```

And use like:

```
Public Event test As MyEventHandler
```

Credits go to Kirill from our team.

Regards,

MC
PD: I don't know why I can't edit my previous answer, so here's this one.

Comment: This seemed to fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This could likely be because of 'Lightweight Solution Loading' is enabled. I had the same issue and when I turned it off it worked, you can do this on the main solution by right clicking and getting the list of the options.

1. Right Click on the main Solution in the Solution Explorer panel.
2. Then select 'Disable Light Weight Solution Load'