# Solution Explorer filter by specific keywords causes crash

Tags: visual-studio-2015, solution-explorer

Certain searches in Solution Explorer are causing Visual Studio to crash:

```
filterchanged
filter
fil
```

Other searches work fine. I have tried rebuilding the solution, resetting all settings, deleting the `.suo` files.

When I attach a debugger (new instance of Visual Studio), the Exception Helper says that this is an AggregateException -- not helping at all. I was unable to find further details.

What can I do to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem with my project except the key word was `delete` This seemed to solve my problem: [Visual Studio 2015 is crashing when searching from Solution Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31742067/visual-studio-2015-is-crashing-when-searching-from-solution-explorer?newreg=9ea63588a23e4bf3be64f9ca5ee5b83a#answer-31972928).

I also noticed that it works fine in /SafeMode.

Problem line:

`Public Event ObjectDeleted(ByVal aString As String)`

---

The workaround is replace your delegates with event handlers:

`Public Delegate Sub MyEventHandler(ByVal s As String)`

And use like:

`Public Event test As MyEventHandler`

I submitted a bug to Microsoft here:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2449669/visual-studio-crashes-when-you-type-delete-into-the-solution-explorer-search

Also found this error:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1606999/vs-2015-professional-crash-when-searching-from-solution-explorer

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Perhaps add that `/SafeMode` works as an answer to the linked question, as well as a link to your Connect ticket?

Comment: @MarianoC also noticed that /SafeMode works in the linked question, and I added it to the workarounds on my connect ticket. 

I'm not sure running Visual Studio in SafeMode is a solution to this problem though